# "the wedding" versus "a wedding"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, emphasis

If I want to talk to my coworkers about my wedding do I say "I had a wedding last month" or do i say "I had the wedding last month"?

Since it is the only wedding I shall ever have, and it is the very important to me, I think I should say "the wedding". "The wedding" just doesn't sound right to me, though I think it is more appropriate because if i say "a wedding", it removes emphasis on how important it was.

Which would be correct in the given context? "I had a wedding last month" or "I had the wedding last month".

Comment: "I had ***my*** wedding last month." You shouldn't use *the* unless the marriage was already a topic in the conversation, and you certainly can't use *a*, for the reasons you've given.

Comment: It may be the only wedding you will ever have, but it is certainly not the only wedding *anybody* will ever have.

Comment: Normally you'd say "I got married".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"I had a wedding last month"* is not idiomatic. It does not sound as though you were the one who got married. It suggests you are a cleric, a wedding photographer or somehow officiated at the ceremony.

We say:

*"I got married last month."*

*"My wedding was last month."* is not the way you would let people know about your marriage. It would be used as additional information, e.g.

*"I'm newly married. The wedding was last month."*

Comment: And why is *"I got married last month"* not also American English? You guys in the U.K. seem to have some funny ideas about how we talk.

Comment: "*I done got married round abouts a month back, I reckon.*"

Comment: @PeterShor I learned on a different forum, never to answer for any variety of English other than my own. It's too easy to make assumptions. If you tell me it's okay, I'm happy to amend my answer :-)

Comment: It's okay. Americans say *"I got married last month"*, too (and probably Australians as well).